# Sprockets unable to locate stylesheets in a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, sprockets

Sprockets is unable to find stylesheets and javascript bundled in a gem. It raises the exception `couldn't find file 'fullcalendar' with type 'text/css'`

My application.css includes `*= require fullcalendar` and the result of running `Rails.application.config.assets.paths` includes `"/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/fullcalendar-rails-2.3.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets"`

From what I understand, require should be looking in the vendor folder for stylesheets named fullcalendar, but it doesn't seem to be.

Are there any configurations I need to make before Sprockets will check this other folder?

Comment: have you run 'gem install fullcalendar-rails'?

Comment: Yes. At elast I added the gem to my gemfile and ran bundle install which I think does the same thing. I also just tried 'gem install fullcalendar-rails' alone and there was no change.

Comment: Have you run the `rails g fullcalendar:install` ? And if yes Have you tried restarting the server after that ?

Comment: Just restarted the server and it's working now. I still have a lot to learn about how all of these components work together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprockets was able to locate the file after I restarted the rails server.

Comment: Is that what you needed to do  ?